# jQuery auto complete solution

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I've had a problem with the autocomplete. Please could you help me solve it.

This my controller code:

```
def new
    @product = Srch.new
end

class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    autocomplete :srch, :name, :full => true do |items|
    CustomJSON::Encoder.encode(items)
end
```

This is my routes file:

```
Search::Application.routes.draw do
    root 'welcome#index'

    resources :products do
        get :autocomplete_srch_name, :on => :collection
    end
end
```

This is my view file:

```
<h1>Search for products</h1>
<%= form_tag("/products/show", method: "get") do %>
<%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:", ) %>
<%= autocomplete_field_tag('srch_name','',autocomplete_srch_name_products_path, :placeholder => "Search", :id => "Main search filter") %>
<%= submit_tag("Search", :name => nil) %>
<% end %>
```

I have my search functionality working but the autocomplete functionality isn't working. Help me with this!